# how to position horizontal line without CSS

Tags: html, position, line

How can you position a horizontal line other than the align attribute? I want to specify the position like 100px from the left and 200px from the top. WITHOUT CSS

Comment: Why can't you use CSS?

Comment: because i have another horizontal line with different position. Or is it possible to set different position for 2 hr using CSS?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use breaks and spaces... <br> and &nbsp;

Comment: of course you can, give them different `id`'s then target them separately in your css or wrap them inside a div for example...

Comment: or you can use `pseudo` `before` and `after` for giving border http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4b0270t9/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set different position for 2 hr. Try using CSS

### html

```
<hr class="hr1" />
<hr class="hr2" />
```

### css

```
.hr1{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
}

.hr2{
   position:absolute;
   top:300px;
   left:400px;
}
```